# ggplot aes: alpha gets "smoothed out"

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha, alpha-transparency

I'm using `ggplot` in the `ggplot2` R package, with the `mpg` data set.

```
classify = function(cls){
    if (cls == "suv" || cls == "pickup"){result = 1}
    else {result = 0}
    return(result)
}
mpg = mpg %>% mutate(size = sapply(class, classify))

ggplot(data = mpg) +
geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, alpha = size))
```

Now, `size` can take only two values: 1 when class is `suv` or `pickup`, and 0 otherwise. But I get a weird "smooth" range of sizes in the resulting plot:

[image]

(It's not the legend that surprises me, but the fact that there are actually values plotted with alpha 0.1 or 0.3 or whatever.)

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (It's not the legend that surprises me, but the fact that there are actually values plotted with alpha 0.1 or 0.3 or whatever.)

There aren’t. What you’re seeing is that multiple points have the exact same discrete coordinates, and so the semi-transparent points overlap.

And to fix the legend, use factors or character strings (= discrete) instead of numbers (= continuous).

---

Unrelated, but your `classify` implementation is pretty unorthodox code. First of all, since R is a functional language, all expressions are *values*. That means that, rather than performing assignment inside an `if` you’d usually assign the result of `if`:

```
result = if (cls == "suv" || cls == "pickup") 1 else 0
```

What’s more, there’s no need for the `result` variable and neither for the `return` function call (which in R performs early exit). Instead, an idiomatic R implementation would look as follows:

```
classify = function(cls) {
    if (cls == "suv" || cls == "pickup") 1 else 0
}
```

Better yet, use vectorised `ifelse` instead of non-vectorised `if`:

```
classify = function(cls) {
    ifelse(cls == "suv" | cls == "pickup", 1, 0)
}
```

Now you can use `classify` without the `sapply`:

```
mpg = mpg %>% mutate(size = classify(class))
```